# Macbook Pro (mid-2012) battery not identified (shows X) after SSD install

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, battery

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro (mid-2012) HDD to SSD.
Once SSD install was complete, my macbook did not start, however when plugged into power, it started booting, and worked normally.

The battery was in decent condition, and was always lasting 3+ hours.

I tried SMC reset, and PRAM reset few times in last few days, however no change in status. On removing the power adapter, it goes to sleep mode.

Very annoying that now onwards, I always have to plug in the power for doing any work.

Any potential hints ...

Comment: Just to make sure, you did double-check that the battery connector was firmly seated, right?  The connector can be loosened without removing the battery itself.  Try using a plastic tool to disconnect the connector and reconnect it.

Comment: Yes, I tried putting the battery connector few times, not working as yet!

Comment: Hmm.  Two other things to try: (1) pop your HDD back in and see what happens, and/or (2) run Apple Hardware Test to determine if there's something wrong with the logic board or something else (Option-D after the startup chime).

Comment: Thx Bob, very useful ... 1) Tried rebooting with HDD, battery is still not recognized. 2) Did hardware test (and extensive test for 2.5 hours), it seemed alright, no hardware issues identified, but showing battery not connected :( ... May be next step, I am thinking of ordering a battery from Amazon to check, if the existing battery got damaged while changing HDD to SSD!

Comment: Yeah, I think ordering another battery to test with is a good idea. Make sure it’s one you can easily return, as we still don’t know exactly what’s broken. The worst-case scenario is that something on the logic board took ESD damage, and a new battery wouldn’t fix that.

Comment: You probably broke the connector.  See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258254/119271  However, there is a possiblity it could be the SATA cable.  Disconnect the SSD, and power up with AC disconnected. If it does, chances are, it's the cable.

Comment: Seems, I broke the battery side of the connector. Got a replacement battery, and its working fine. Is there a way, I can fix the battery connector ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you’ve described, it sounds like you may have accidentally damaged something internal during your upgrade. Since Apple Hardware Test didn’t turn up anything, ordering a replacement battery is a reasonable next step. If that doesn’t work, then there must be damage to the logic board. You can get tested replacement boards for around $200 or so [on eBay](https://m.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=macbook%20pro%2013%202012%20logic%20board).

Comment: Replacement battery has worked. So may be the battery connector got damaged. Need to find, if I can fix battery connector.